# how to drop one element from one div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following div

```
<div class="npwfu-inspiration">
    <div class="npwfu-inspiration-inner">
        <h1>Looking for inspiration?</h1>

        <p>Pick a category to see examples of what you can create with Spark.</p>
        <ul class="inspiration-category-list"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

I need to take out the inspiration-category-list list ul and drop it into another div with a CSS transition. So it slides down and locks to position 80px from the top in div2.

How can I do this using JQUERY?

Comment: CSS only won't do that  AFAIK

Comment: She said "How can I do this using JQUERY?" :)

Comment: @TomMettam The question was edited...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a coding service. You should minimally show what you've attempted and where you are having trouble.

Comment: once you use jquery to manipulate the DOM (using remove and append for instance) it will be removed and added. So you need to do the transition of the UL in the first div to the desired position first and then remove it from the dom and add it to the other div with jquery at the same position. But looking at your idea, I think you want maybe to look into draggable/droppable of https://jqueryui.com

Answer (score 0):

why you do not use drag effect instead of css transition?
 if you would like you can add draggable effect to every element that you want to move it
you can use dragable.js from link below
then in javascript code you should set $`(".inspiration-category-list").draggable ()`
then instead of using css transition just drag it and drop it in any div element

```js
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
Draggable
alternative to jQuery UI’s draggable
based on comments from: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/
usage example: $('.post-thumbnail, article header').draggable();
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
(function ($) {
    if (!jQuery().draggable) {
        $.fn.draggable = function () {
            var _fixMobileEvent = function (e) {
                if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.targetTouches && e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0]) {
                    var t = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
                    e.pageX = t.clientX;
                    e.pageY = t.clientY;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            this
                .css('cursor', 'move')
                .on('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {
                    _fixMobileEvent(e);
                    var $dragged = $(this);

                    var startOffset = $dragged.offset();
                    var x = startOffset.left - e.pageX,
                        y = startOffset.top - e.pageY,
                        z = $dragged.css('z-index');

                    if (!$.fn.draggable.stack) {
                        $.fn.draggable.stack = 999;
                    }
                    stack = $.fn.draggable.stack;
                    var firstMove = true;
                    var $preventClick = null;

                    $(window)
                        .on('mousemove.draggable touchmove.draggable', function (e) {
                            _fixMobileEvent(e);
                            //$("#log").text("x: " + e.pageX + "; y: " + e.pageY);

                            if (firstMove) {
                                firstMove = false;
                                $dragged
                                    .css({
                                        'z-index': stack, 'transform': 'scale(1.1)', 'transition': 'transform .3s',
                                        'bottom': 'auto', 'right': 'auto'
                                    });
                                /*.find('a').one('click.draggable', function(e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                    $("#log").text("link: click prevented " + stack);
                                });*/
                                var $target = $(e.target);
                                if ($target.is('a')) {
                                    $preventClick = $target;
                                    $target.one('click.draggable', function (e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                        //$("#log").text("link: click prevented " + stack);
                                    });
                                } else if ($dragged.is('a')) {
                                    $preventClick = $dragged;
                                    $dragged.one('click.draggable', function (e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                        //$("#log").text("dragged: click prevented " + stack);
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            $dragged.offset({
                                left: x + e.pageX,
                                top: y + e.pageY
                            });
                            e.preventDefault();
                        })
                        .one('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function () {
                            $(this).off('mousemove.draggable touchmove.draggable');
                            $dragged.css({ 'z-index': z, 'transform': 'scale(1)' })
                            $.fn.draggable.stack++;
                            if (_fixMobileEvent(e)) {
                                if ($preventClick) $preventClick.off('click.draggable');
                                var endOffset = $dragged.offset();
                                //$("#log").text("left :" + startOffset.left + "; top: " + startOffset.top
                                //               + "; newLeft: " + endOffset.left + "; newTop: " + endOffset.top);
                                if (Math.abs(endOffset.left - startOffset.left) <= 3
                                        && Math.abs(endOffset.top - startOffset.top) <= 3) {

                                    if ($preventClick) {
                                        $preventClick[0].click();
                                    } else {
                                        var $target = $(e.target);
                                        if ($target.is('a')) {
                                            e.target.click();
                                        } else if ($dragged.is('a')) {
                                            $dragged[0].click();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            return this;
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```